# Computation for Measure of non-compactness of a set in $(C[0,1],||.||_\infty)$

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

There is an exemple i didn't understand how they calculate the measure of noncompactness, could you pleasse help me on it?

Let $X=C([0,1])$ be the Banach space of all continuous real functions on $[0,1]$ endowed with the maximum norm., $\ B(X)=\{x\in X\mid \|x\|\leq 1\}$, we have

$$M=\{u\in B(X)\mid 0\leq u(0)\leq \frac{1}{3},\ 0\leq u(t)\leq 1,\ \frac{2}{3}\leq u(1)\leq 1\}$$
then
$$\gamma(M)=\frac{1}{2},\quad\gamma_0(M)=\frac{2}{3},\quad \alpha(M)=1, $$
Reminder: Let $E$ be a Banach space, $A$ non empty bounded subset of $E,$

$\alpha$  the Kuratowski measure of noncompactness,  defined by
$$\alpha(A)=\inf\left\{\delta>0 \mid \  A=\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{n} A_{i},\  A_i \subset \ E \mbox{ et } diam(A_{i})\leq \delta,\quad \forall i=1,\dots,n,\ n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}$$         $\gamma$  the Hausdorff measure of noncompactness, defined by
$$\gamma(A)=\inf\left\{\varepsilon>0 \mid A\subset\bigcup \limits_{i=1}^{n}B(x_{i},r_{i}),\  x_{i}\in E,\ r_{i}<\varepsilon, i=1,2,\dots,n,\ n\in \mathbb{N}\right\}$$
$\gamma_0$ Inner-Hausdorff measure of non-compactness. defined by
$$\gamma_0(A)=\inf\left\{\varepsilon>0 \mid  A\subset\bigcup \limits_{i=1}^{n}B(x_{i},r_{i}),\ x_{i}\in A,\ r_{i}<\varepsilon, i=1,2,\dots,n,\ n\in \mathbb{N}\right\}$$
$diam$ is the diameter of a set

Thank you,
Best regards

Comment: What have you figured out so far?

Comment: Should it not follow from the definition that $\gamma_0\geq\gamma\geq \alpha$ as opposed to what you have provided?

Comment: If $(X,d)$ is a complete metric space and $A$ is a nonempty bounded subset of $X$. Then we have: $$\gamma(A)\leq \alpha(A)\leq 2\gamma(A).$$.From where did you get $\alpha\leq \gamma\leq \gamma_0$? Could you please provide me the reference @NewB ?

Comment: My bad. You are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets start with $\gamma_0$. Consider the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{3}(x+1)$ (the line which joints $(0,\frac{1}{3})$ and $(1,\frac{2}{3})$). Clearly $f\in M$. Consider a ball $B(f,\frac{2}{3})$ centered at $f$. Notice that for any $g\in M$ we have $||g-f||_\infty<\frac{2}{3}$ and hence $M\subset B(f,\frac{2}{3})$. Thus $\gamma_0(M)\leq \frac{2}{3}$.

Now suppose that  $\delta>0$ be such that $\delta<\frac{2}{3}$ and $f_1,...,f_n\in M$ be functions such that $M\subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^n B(f_i,r_i)$ where $r_i<\delta$ for each $i=1,2,..,n$.

Since, each $f_i$ is continuous we can chose a corresponding $x_i$ small enough such that $1-f(x_i)>\delta$ (because as $x$ approaches zero, the value of $1-f_i(x)$ approaches $1-f(0)\geq \frac{2}{3}$). We can rearrange the order of $f_i$'s in such  a way that $x_1\leq x_2\leq...\leq x_n$. Now, let $g$ denote a function which is a piecewise straight lines joining the points $(0,\frac{1}{3})$, $(x_1,1)$, $(x_n,1)$ and $(1,\frac{2}{3})$.
Clearly $g\in M$ but one can see that $g\notin B(f_i,r_i)$ for any $i=1,2,..,n$. To see this notice that if $g\in B(f_i,r_i)$ then it should follow that $|g(x_i)-f_i(x_i)|<r_i$.  But  $|g(x_i)-f(x_i)|=1-f(x_i)>\delta>r_i$ because of the way $x_i$'s were chosen. Thus, our assumption was wrong and $M$ cannot be contained in any finite collection of balls centered at the points of $M$ and of radius less $\frac{2}{3}$

Hence, we have $\gamma_0(M)> \delta$. Since $\delta<\frac{2}{3}$ was arbitrary, we conclude that $\gamma_0(M)\geq \frac{2}{3}$, while we already had $\gamma_0(M)\leq \frac{2}{3}$. Combining both we get $\gamma_0(M)=\frac{2}{3}$.

I think you can get the gist for $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ from this. One can easily see that $\alpha(M)\leq 1$ and $\gamma(M)\leq \frac{1}{2}$ because $M\subset B(\mathbb 1,\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon)$ for each $\epsilon>0$, where $\mathbb 1$ denotes the unit function.

Now let $\delta<1$ and $M\subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^nA_i$ where $diam(A_i)\leq \delta$ for each $i=1,2,..,n$. Now choose an infinite increasing sequence $\{a_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ in $(0,1)$. Consider a sequence of wedge like piecewise straightline functions $\{f_k\}$ such that $f_k(0)=\frac{1}{3}$, $f_k(1)=1$ and $f_k(a_1)=1$, $f_k(a_2)=0$, $f_k(a_3)=1,...,f_k(a_k)=0$ (or 1 depending on $k$ being even or odd) and finally joining $(a_k,f_k(a_k))$ to $(1,1)$ by straight line. Notice that $f_k\in M$ for each $k\in \mathbb N$ and $||f_k-f_{k'}||=1$ for any pair of distinct natural number $k$ and $k'$. Thus set $A_i$ of diameter $\delta<1$ can atmost contain only one of these $f_k$'s. So a finite number of these sets cannot cover $M$. Hence, $\alpha(M)>\delta$ and since $\delta<1$ was arbitrary, we know that $\alpha(M)\geq 1$ , while we already mentioned above that $\alpha(M)\leq 1$, thus concluding that $\alpha(M)=1$.

Finally, using the equality $\alpha(M)\leq 2\gamma(M)$, we conclude that $\gamma(M)\geq \frac{1}{2}$, while $\gamma(M)\leq \frac{1}{2}$ is already known as mentioned above. Hence, $\gamma(M)=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: thank you so much for your kind help!

Comment: Glad you found it helpful.

Comment: In some paper they refer to the following reference  for exemple of computing a measure of non-compactness: "M. Furi, M. Martelli, On the minimal displacement of points under $\alpha$-Lipschitz maps innormed spaces, Boll. Unione Mat. Ital., IV-9 (1974), 791-799" . Could you provide me this reference if you have it?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have access to that paper in any form.

Comment: Thank you @NewB